Importing files at the cursor instead of the beginning of the timeline
I would like to import files at the cursor on the timeline, instead of the beginning as After Effects does now. Would make it much more practical, but I do not see a option to make that happen.
Is there  way to make this happen?

I don't think it's possible. But you can use a single keyboard shortcut to jump any of your selected clips to the cursor point: Press [.
